# Bootstrap 3's inline list class not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have Bootstrap 3 integrated into my web application. I am trying to style secondary/drop-down menus from the main nav so the items are displayed inline. The Bootstrap 3 class for this is `<ul class="list-inline">` (that  obviously being the nested one), but it is not working.

I see the associated CSS rules come through in Chrome devtools, so it's not a cache issue. The class and rules are being applied, and the declaration is not being overridden (no strike-through line). The markup structure is as follows:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown open">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/item1">Item 1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu list-inline">
        <li><a href="/item1/subitem1">SubItem 1</a></li>
        <!-- Some more secondary nav <li>'s here... -->
      </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- Some more primary nav <li>'s here... -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

There are many style rules being applied to the various classes here, so I'm only pasting in the CSS for the nested `<ul>`...

```
.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 3em;
  background-color: #525252;
}
/* I didn't write any of these styles - maybe Bootstrap's? */
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  <strike>display: none;</strike>
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  <strike>background-color: blah blah</strike>
  <strike>border: blah blah</strike>
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

...and the child list items...

```
.list-inline > li:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.list-inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
  <strike>padding-left: 5px;</strike>
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

I have also tried manually adding `display: inline` and `inline-block`, as well as `float: left`, but nothing has worked. If it's relevant, I'm using Sass (SCSS) for the CSS, and the Sass 3.2.3 and Bootstrap gems (this is a Rails app). The styles are all compiling into one big `application.css` file using `@import` directives.

Comment: Perhaps create a jsfiddle for people to play with. Reference the bootstrap CDN. I suspect that list-inline and classes are conflicting with each other because there is nothing (that I've seen) in the bootstrap docs about the specific scenario you are shooting for. Out of the box, I'm doubtful it's supported, but a jsfiddle would help everyone come up with a customized solution.

Comment: Test to rewrite it with the `!important` property.

Comment: While the addition of `!important` didn't have an effect, I solved it by increasing the `min-width` property's value to 500px. You'd think it would have expanded since that declaration was only for a _minimum_ width, but it's all done. Thank you for your feedback.